# Complex Search with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've always had problems forming a search request in ES.
Now, I have to update my code from v.2 to v.6 and a lot is different.
Current problem: how can I formulate a complex `or` and `and` search?
Right now I have:

```
{
    "index":"<index>",
    "type":"<type>",
    "body":{
        "from":0,
        "size":20,
        "query":{
            "bool":{
                "must":{
                    "or":{
                        "match":{
                            "CUSTNR":"24508"
                        },
                        "and":{
                            "prefix":[
                                {
                                    "ORDERNR":"128"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I receive the message: `{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [or]"`

How should I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing called AND/OR in elasticsearch 6 or later, It is mapped like this way

1. **AND** is **must**
2. **OR** is **should**
3. **NOR** is **should_not**

So if you want to see all the customer with **CUSTNR = 24508 AND ORDERNR = (128 OR 129)** then we can build the query like below where `bool` indicates we are using boolean operator

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {   
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {"CUSTNR ": 24508 }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {"term": {"ORDERNR ": 128}},
                            {"term": {"ORDERNR ": 129}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

A sample complex query added for your understanding how to form must, should, sort etc.

https://gist.github.com/sany2k8/ec0145738babca643f0a369e55546c85

Comment: Thanks! that helps a lot.

Comment: Be careful, `should` is not always a **OR**. In your example query, if none of the `should` statements are verified but at least one of the `must` statement is verified, the document will be returned. To enforce **OR** behavior you must add `minimum_should_match: 1` to the `bool` query. See `should` in [the document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel agreed with you sir, thnx for that comment